# I have a PHP files, so how to validate PHP files on W3C validator?

Tags: php, validation, w3c

How to validate PHP files? I have tried but I'm getting an error "Sorry! This document can not be checked." Help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

W3C validates HTML and XHTML.

You can only validate the HTML-Output of your PHP script.

Your PHP-Output must be reachable with a URL for W3C validator

https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_uri

or you can save the output and upload to W3C validator.

https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_upload